An Inequality Concerning the Roots of a transcendental equation
Let $f(x)=x(1-\ln x)$ and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. If $a,b$ are the distinct roots of $f(1+({\rm e}-2)x)=c$,while e is the base of the natural logarithm,prove that:
$$0<c<1<a+b+2c<2$$
My Attempt:Firstly it is easy to prove $0<c<1$:while$$f'(x)=-\ln x$$
Thus, the function is monotonically increasing on (0,1) and monotonically decreasing on (1,+∞). Additionally, $f(e)=0$, and for $x>e$, we have $f(x)<0$.We only need to calculate the range of values of $ f(x) $ on the interval (0, e). Since the limit of $ f(x) $ as $ x $ approaches 0 is 0, the range of values is $(0, 1]$. Therefore, $$0 < c < 1$$
Then consider $1<a+b+2c<2$.I have no idea about the left side,but to the right side,maybe we can firstly prove $a+b+c<1$ and it has been tested by software,but I still have no idea.

Please provide what you have tried in your post

You might be able to make use of a piecewise linear approximation. You know the roots of the function and its maximum, if you just join these you can get approximations for $a$ and $b$ for a given $c$, and know whether they're too large or too small.

@ChrisLewis I would appreciate it if you could show me the method of piecewise linear approximation when you have time.

@SlashQwerty For convenience let's define $f(1+(e-2)x)=:g(x)$. The graph of $y=g(x)$ is a translation and scaling in the $x$-direction of the graph of $y=f(x)$, so the analysis you've done for $f$ basically still applies. $g(x)$ has a negative root at $(-K,0)$, a maximum at $(0,1)$ and a positive root at $(1+K,0)$ (you can find $K$ easily enough). The approximation I'm talking about is the piecewise linear function you get by joining the roots to the maximum point with straight line segments. You can show that this function is below $g(x)$, and that (might) help with the inequalities.

Here is a proof using the implicit differentiation.
Remarks. I tried this approach yesterday but was stuck at the proof of $F'(c) > 0$. Now I can proceed. I learned this approach some years ago from @G.Kós's answer for this question. By the way, I noticed that @Macavity has tried this way as well.
Let $a_1 := 1 + (\mathrm{e} - 2)a$
and $b_1 := 1 + (\mathrm{e} - 2)b$.
Then $a_1, b_1 > 0$ are two distinct real roots of $f(x) = c$ given that $0 < c < 1$. We need to prove that
$$1 < \frac{a_1 + b_1 - 2}{\mathrm{e} - 2} + 2c < 2. \tag{1}$$
WLOG, assume that $a_1 < b_1$.
Since $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $(0, 1)$ and strictly decreasing on $(1, \infty)$, and $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} f(x) = 0$, and $f(x) \le 0$ for all $x \ge \mathrm{e}$, we have $0 < a_1 < 1 < b_1 < \mathrm{e}$.
For $0 < c < 1$, the two real roots $a_1 = a_1(c)$ and $b_1 = b_1(c)$ are functions of $c$ satisfying
$$a_1(c) - a_1(c) \ln a_1(c) = 
b_1(c) - b_1(c) \ln b_1(c) = c.$$
By implicit differentiation, we have
$$a_1'(c) - a_1'(c)\ln a_1(c) - a_1(c) \frac{1}{a_1(c)}a_1'(c) = 1, $$
and
$$b_1'(c) - b_1'(c)\ln b_1(c) - b_1(c) \frac{1}{b_1(c)}b_1'(c) = 1$$
which result in
$$a_1'(c) = -\frac{1}{\ln a_1(c)}, 
\quad b_1'(c) = - \frac{1}{\ln b_1(c)}.$$
Now, let
$$F(c) := \frac{a_1(c) + b_1(c) - 2}{\mathrm{e} - 2} + 2c.$$
We have
$$
 F'(c) = \frac{a_1'(c) + b_1'(c)}{\mathrm{e} - 2} + 2
 = \frac{-\frac{1}{\ln a_1(c)} - \frac{1}{\ln b_1(c)}}{\mathrm{e} - 2} + 2
 > 0. \tag{2}
$$
The proof of (2) is given at the end.
Also, $\lim_{c\to 0^{+}} F(c) = 1$ and $\lim_{c\to 1^{-}} F(c) = 2$.
Thus, we have $1 < F(c) < 2$.
We are done.

Proof of (2).
If $0 < c \le \frac13$,
we have $f(7/3) = \frac73 - \frac73 \ln \frac73 > \frac13 \ge c = f(b_1(c))$ which results in $b_1(c) \ge \frac73$. Thus, we have
$$\frac{-\frac{1}{\ln a_1(c)} - \frac{1}{\ln b_1(c)}}{\mathrm{e} - 2} + 2 > \frac{ - \frac{1}{\ln b_1(c)}}{\mathrm{e} - 2} + 2 \ge \frac{ - \frac{1}{\ln \frac73}}{\mathrm{e} - 2} + 2 > 0.$$
If $c > \frac13$,
we have $f(1/10) = \frac{1}{10} - \frac{1}{10}\ln \frac{1}{10} < \frac13 < c = f(a_1(c))$ which results in
$a_1(c) \ge \frac{1}{10}$. Using $a_1(c) + b_1(c) \ge 2$ (the proof is given in my previous answer), we have
$$\frac{-\frac{1}{\ln a_1(c)} - \frac{1}{\ln b_1(c)}}{\mathrm{e} - 2} + 2
\ge \frac{-\frac{1}{\ln a_1(c)} - \frac{1}{\ln [2 - a_1(c)]}}{\mathrm{e} - 2} + 2 \ge \frac{-\frac43}{\mathrm{e} - 2} + 2 > 0$$
where we use $-\frac{1}{\ln u} - \frac{1}{\ln (2-u)} \ge - \frac43$ for all $1/10 \le u < 1$ (the proof is given at the end).
We are done.

Proof of $-\frac{1}{\ln u} - \frac{1}{\ln (2-u)} \ge - \frac43$ for all $1/10 \le u < 1$.
After clearing the denominators, it suffices to prove that
$$G(u) := -4\ln u \ln (2 - u) + 3\ln u + 3\ln (2 - u) \ge 0.$$
Let $H(u) := G'(u)u(2-u)$. We have
$$H''(u) = \frac{8(1-u)}{u(2-u)} > 0.$$
Also, $H(1) = 0$ and $H(1/10) < 0$. Thus,
$H(u) \le 0$ on $[-1/10, 1)$.
Thus, $G'(u) \le 0$ on $[-1/10, 1)$.
Also, $G(1) = 0$. Thus, $G(u) \ge 0$ on $[-1/10, 1)$.
We are done.

Here is a proof for $1 < a + b + 2c$.
Let $a_1 := 1 + (\mathrm{e} - 2)a$
and $b_1 := 1 + (\mathrm{e} - 2)b$.
Then $a_1, b_1 > 0$ are two distinct real roots of $f(x) = c$ given that $0 < c < 1$. We need to prove that
$$1 < \frac{a_1 + b_1 - 2}{\mathrm{e} - 2} + 2c. \tag{1}$$
WLOG, assume that $a_1 < b_1$.
Since $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $(0, 1)$ and strictly decreasing on $(1, \infty)$, and $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} f(x) = 0$, and $f(x) \le 0$ for all $x \ge \mathrm{e}$, we have $0 < a_1 < 1 < b_1 < \mathrm{e}$.
We claim that $a_1 + b_1 \ge 2$.
Indeed, letting $$g(a_1) := f(2- a_1) - f(b_1)
= (2-a_1)[1 - \ln(2 - a_1)] - a_1(1 - \ln a_1),$$
we have $g'(a_1) = \ln(2 - a_1) + \ln a_1
= \ln(1 - (1-a_1)^2) < 0$ and $g(1) = 0$, which results in $g(a_1) \ge 0$ and thus $2 - a_1 \le b_1$. The claim is proved.
If $c > 1/2$, using $a_1+b_1\ge 2$, (1) is clearly true.
If $0 < c \le 1/2$, it suffices to prove that
$$1 \le \frac{b_1 - 2}{\mathrm{e} - 2} + 2c, $$
or
$$b_1 \ge \mathrm{e} - 2(\mathrm{e}-2)c.$$
Note that $\mathrm{e} - 2(\mathrm{e}-2)c > 1$. Let
$$h(c) := f(\mathrm{e} - 2(\mathrm{e}-2)c) - f(b_1)
= f(\mathrm{e} - 2(\mathrm{e}-2)c) - c.$$
We have $h''(c) = - \frac{4(\mathrm{e}-2)^2}{\mathrm{e} - 2(\mathrm{e}-2)c} < 0$ (concave)
and $h(0) = 0$ and $h(1/2) > 0 $,
which results in $h(c) \ge 0$ on $(0, 1/2]$ and thus $b_1 \ge \mathrm{e} - 2(\mathrm{e}-2)c$. (1) is true.
We are done.

Thank you for your perfect answer.

@SlashQwerty You are welcome.
